# How to set position of mapbox-gl-draw control?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl-draw

I'm using https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw for draw tools, and it by default sets the control position to the top right. Like so:
[image]

It seems like it's possible to change the position of the control by setting an option, but I cannot figure out how to do so. I've been looking through the source and the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set the position in the [`addControl`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addcontrol) method.

```
var Draw = new MapboxDraw();

map.addControl(Draw, 'bottom-left');
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason thought that would be controlled by the Draw. But makes sense that the map handles the positioning.

Comment: Yep it's a little confusing. I added more information in the example here https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw#usage-in-your-application

Answer (score 2):

[addControl( control, position )](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#addcontrol)

**Parameters**

position(string?), position on the map to which the control will be added.
Valid values are

- **'top-left'**
- **'top-right'**
- **'bottom-left'**
- **'bottom-right'**

Defaults to **'top-right'**

[Example App](https://antelove.com/blog/read/1605262398)